# Azure AD B2C get token programatically for unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

My scenario is simple I have a simple Azure Function with B2C authentication on it and I'm writing unit tests but I found an issue, I'm not able to authenticate to the azure functions programmatically.

I'm able to access through the browser and even I can grab the token and put it into the unit test and it works fine, but when I try to generate a token using the ClientID, TenantID, etc. I get a token, but 401 Unauthorized response on the Azure functions.

**Is there a way to generate a valid B2C token programmatically (without login in the browser?**

The approach I'm using so far:

```
public static async  Task<AuthenticationResult> GetAccessToken(string resourceUri, string clientId, string clientSecret)
{
        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

        string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
        string tenant = "<mytenant>.onmicrosoft.com";
        string authority = string.Concat(aadInstance, tenant);
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        return await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientCredential);
}
```

I'm getting a token (EY.......) but is not valid, when I passed to the Azure Function request, it returns 401 Unauthorized.

Thanks in advance!
Ivan

Comment: I've met the same problem. Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @SerhiiBond I've updated the answer with detailed info. Hope it helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of months ago, Microsoft released a policy for resource owner password credentials flow, with that policy you can simulate a login passing the login details in a query as follows:

1. Create a ROPC policy in B2C
2. Register an application
3. Test the policy as follows:

   ```
     https://te.cpim.windows.net/{B2C TENANT}/{ROPC B2C POLICY}/oauth2/v2.0/token?username={USERNAME}&password={password}&grant_type=password&scope=openid+{CLIENT ID}+offline_access&client_id=[CLIENT ID]&response_type=token+id_token
   ```

You can find more detailed info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I  went another way and imitated login throw MS form using HttpWebRequest class. So there is no UI part, just http requests and thats suit me perfect for my API autotests

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your unit test is acquiring a token from the Azure AD v1.0 endpoint rather than the Azure AD B2C v2.0 endpoint.

Your Azure function is expecting the token to be issued by the Azure AD B2C v2.0 endpoint.

In the short term, you can consider acquiring the token from the Azure AD B2C v2.0 endpoint by replaying the browser requests using the `HttpClient` class.

In the near term, [support for the resource owner password credential grant by Azure AD B2C](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13817784-add-support-for-resource-owner-password-credential) will enable your unit test to acquire a token from the Azure AD B2C v2.0 endpoint by POSTing a user credential to the endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In order to validate as the right answer, for the short term, please, could you provide more guidance on this?  I've read the V2.0 [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-access-tokens) and looks like you need to interact with the browser to get the token. How can I simulate this with the `HttpClient` class? Thanks again!