# How to get my Unit Tests to bypass the Authorize tag on my .NET Web Controller

Tags: .net, unit-testing, moq, authorize-attribute

I have a Web API in .NET 4.6.1 and my controllers are Azure B2C protected.
Hence, they have the [Authorize] tag.

I wrote a Unit Test to ensure that I can hit the route and test some business logic. However, I cannot figure out how to bypass the [Authorize] tag and I do not want to authorize with B2C for each unit test that runs.

I am assuming that mocking the Controller Context would be a good start but I am having trouble figuring out the syntax.

There are a few articles about mocking the ControllerContext and then setting the `HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated` but this applies to MVC.

I get an error converting from `System.Web.MVC.ControllerContext` to `System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext`.

Cannot implicitly convert type error:

[image: Cannot implicitly convert type error]

I am hoping that someone can help me figure out how to bypass the `[Authorize]` tag for my unit tests?

Comment: If you have an separate Dev-environment it would be good to have an extra Identityprovider for this "stage". This can be configured and used with test-accounts. So you can also test several roles and user rights with your tests.
I use https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/Getting-Started-with-oidc-provider for local environment.

Comment: Are these tests part of a CI build? Are they executed when the code is build?

Comment: Yes, they are part of a CI build.

Comment: This question seems similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307985/azure-ad-b2c-get-token-programatically-for-unit-testing

Comment: I've tried this already but as per my original question, I do not think that it's best practice to be hitting B2C during unit testing. Is there a way to bypass the [Authorize] tag?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have different usings in your file, so your mock is a

```
Mock<System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext>
```

And not a

```
Mock<System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext>
```

If you specify the namespace, that can fix that problem.

I would however split up the tests instead, moving your business logic from an authorised controller and into its own class you can more easily test.

And I'm sure there are ways of testing your routes.

Comment: splitting the business logic from the authorizations is the best solution here. That will make testing a lot easier.

Comment: I've explicitly tried to Mock System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext but then I cannot access HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated.
Hence, why I need to Mock ControllerContext.

Comment: I agree that splitting the business logic from the Auth will do the job but I also want to ensure that I can hit the route and test response status codes and returned messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your tests in debug, it's possible to bypass the authorization attribute by using **preprocessor directives**. You can use these to remove certain parts from compilation in debug mode (or release mode). The following example shows how to remove the authorization attribute in DEBUG mode, while leaving it in in RELEASE mode

```
#if !DEBUG
[Authorize]
#endif
public class MyController : Controller
{
    // controller logic
}
```

I would advise to read more about [preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/) before using them. This sollution is very dependent on the mode in which the tests are run.

Comment: This means that I cannot run Unit Tests as part of my Release Builds. I'm pretty sure that there's a proper an easy way to get around the Authorize tag? I wonder how others do it.